SoftDelete issue
I am encountering an issue with the @SoftDelete annotation in my entity class. It forces eager loading, which is causing performance issues.
Consider the following class:
@Entity
@Data
@SoftDelete
public class OrgUnit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @NotFound
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private OrgUnit parent;
}

When I try to read a leaf node by its ID, it reads all the parent nodes recursively. This happens because @SoftDelete forces eager loading, even though I have specified FetchType.LAZY for the parent association.
According to the documentation, @NotFound and FetchType.LAZY cannot be used together for @ManyToOne and @OneToOne associations. They are forced to use eager fetching.
OrgUnit.parent uses both @NotFound and FetchType.LAZY.
@ManyToOne and @OneToOne associations mapped with @NotFound are forced to EAGER fetching.

How can I use @SoftDelete with lazy loading? Any help would be appreciated.

Hello, can you share the code when you are trying to make to make the delete please ?

The problem is not in delete.  The problem is in fetch.  It fetches eagerly. For instance it fetches leaf,  then parent, then gradparent until root.

Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. So there's something I don't understand. At one point you say that SoftDelete causes an eager fetch. Then you say that NotFound causes an eager fetch. So your problem is the NotFound and not the SoftDelete, isn't it?

@NotFound annotation is needed.  Otherwise hibernate complains about the mapping.  The issue is  using soft delete future forces eager fetching as it is logged as warning.
